# image stabilization on RC plane camera

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, image-stabilization

I have a RC plane and I am using a Raspberry Pi 3 to catch images of a still area using an IR camera.

I camera takes pictures every 10 secs

The **problem** is due to the shake on the RC place the pictures are wobbly.

Can anyone suggest any algorithmic solution for this problem?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Unfortunately, this question is off topic for our site, as questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Two remarks : 1. That question would belong in the  [signal processing site](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/) 2. What do you mean by wobbly ? Show pictures, be as decriptive as possible, we are not mediums. **As is, your question cannot be answered.**

Comment: 1. I am a new learner not an expert but thank you for pointing that out. 2.Wobbly is a pure english word  - Wobbly means - unsteadily moving (https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/wobbly) Since the RC plane will not be stable in air because of differential lift and drags coefficients the images from the camera will be stable. 3. I dont have a picture for that. Anyways thank for the help